# Setting custom width for a td without colspan

Tags: html, css

I am not good in using table. I am using twitter bootstrap, i have only two td in my 5th row, i want my last `td` to be just below the last `td` of the 4th row.
I know it can be done if i put `colspan=3` for the first `td` of 5th row. but i dont want to use `colspan`, As i am using html5 and i want to keep layout in different file. Is thr any css way of doing this?

My Table is Like

_   _   _   _

_   _   _   _

_   _   _   _

_   _   _   _

____        _

Edit:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Z3G/)
I want the Order total to stay thr, but i want the Rs. 900 to come exactly below Total Price

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the situation you have?

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle ??

Comment: why do you not want to use colspan?

Comment: you have to switch to css table layouting of elements representing your cells ([see here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)), if you do not want to employ the `colspan` attribute. alternatively, you may get along with explicitly setting widths and borders of your `td` elements, using the 2nd `td` in place of the 5th and having 3 trailing  empty cells in your last row. as should be obvious from the description, this recipe is a hack and most certainly won't work  cross-browser (in case it does at all).

Comment: It's nice that you have shared the code, but you still didn't explain why is not possible use colspan. You can do it with script but it's excess.

Comment: You mention that you wish to keep layout in a separate file. you could argue, however, that defining your table structure is document structure rather than layout. so add colspan attributes to your html table definition and keep the css clauses in a separate file and your project will still remain 'clean'.

Comment: I can use colspan, are their no other way of acheiving this

Comment: you can put three empty `<td></td>` tags before total price and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. The `colspan` attribute is *the* tool for making one cell occupy several slots in the horizontal direction. If you want just a tabular layout without playing by the HTML rules for a `table` element, use other methods, e.g. use `div` elements instead of table cells and position them with CSS.

Comment: I have provided fiddle link, Can you tell me is it possible

Comment: As my answer says, it is not possible. The jsfiddle illustrates what you are doing, and you should really use `colspan`. The element with “Rs. 900” does not *belong to* the second column (which has the header “Item Name”) but to the fifth column. The `colspan` attribute is the way to express this *structural* relationship and, en passant, place the data in the proper column visually. Another alternative is to add three empty cells between two cells you now have on the last row, but that’s less natural and complicates styling.